# css Adjust the size for horizontal drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to have some control over the width of the menu bar, as an example it would be great if each item only used 5px for each side as padding.  Presently the entire menu uses too much screen width on mobile devices.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<meta name="viewport" content="Width=device-Width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
.drop_menu {
position: relative;
background: #005555;
list-style-type: none;
height: 40px;
width: 460px;
display: flex;
padding: 0;
margin:0 auto;
background-image: url("http://snaklvr.com/bg.jpg");
}
img {
float: center;
}
.drop_menu li a {
padding: 12px 20px;
display: inline-block;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
font: 12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}
.drop_menu > li {
border-right: 1px solid #75809a;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
}
.drop_menu > li:last-child {
border-right: none;
}
/* Submenu */
.drop_menu ul {
text-align: left;
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
top: -9999px;
list-style-type: none;
display: inline;
}
.drop_menu li:hover {
position: relative;
background: #75809a;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul {
left: 0px;
top: 38px;
background: #75809a;
padding: 0px;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
padding: 10px;
display: block;
width: 168px;
text-indent: 15px;
background-color: #75809a;
}
.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
background: #005555;
}

tbody div{
overflow:scroll;
height:400px;
}

#InTheCenter {
text-align:center;
}


div.topdiv {
clear: both;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
height: 60%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #bfb9b5;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;
left: 400;
}

div.bottomdiv {
clear: both;
position: fixed;
top: 60%;
height: 40%;
width: 100%;
background-color: #bfb9b5;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 16px;
text-align: center;
}


</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
var LeftsideMeetingsPopup = ((document.documentElement.clientWidth / 2) - 550);
var TopOfMeetingsPopup = ((document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2) - 300);

var LeftsideEventsPopup = ((document.documentElement.clientWidth / 2) - 310);
var TopOfEventsPopup = ((document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2) - 180);

var MeetingsParams = 'Width=1100,Height=600,Left=' + LeftsideMeetingsPopup + ',Top=' + TopOfMeetingsPopup + ',scrollbars=no';
var EventsParams = 'Width=620,Height=360,Left=' + LeftsideEventsPopup + ',Top=' + TopOfEventsPopup + ',scrollbars=no';


function Meetings_Popup(mylink, windowname) {
if (!window.focus) return true;
var href;
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') href = mylink;
else href = mylink.href;
window.open(href, windowname, MeetingsParams);
return false;
}

function Events_Popup(mylink, windowname) {
if (!window.focus) return true;
var href;
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string') href = mylink;
else href = mylink.href;
window.open(href, windowname, EventsParams);
return false;
}
</SCRIPT>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#bfb9b5">
<div class="topdiv">
<div class="InTheCenter">
<br/><img src="http://snaklvr.com/test.jpg" width="940" height="200"><br/>
</div>
<div>
</BR>
<ul class="drop_menu">
<li><A href="#" onClick="return Meetings_Popup(this, 'notes')">Meeting List</a></li>
<li><A href="#" onClick="return Events_Popup(this, 'notes')">Events</a></li>
<li>
<A href='#'>Misc Links</a>
<ul>
<li><A target="_blank" href="http://www.amazon.com/">Amazon</a></li>
<li><A target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
<li><A target="_blank" href="https://lowes.com/">Lowes</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please add a jsfiddle.net

Comment: Added code to https://jsfiddle.net/sfp4n88b/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `width` of the menu to `max-width` so that it will scale to a smaller size, and change the horizontal padding on the links to 5px (or whatever you want to use there)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="Width=device-Width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .drop_menu {
      position: relative;
      background: #005555;
      list-style-type: none;
      height: 40px;
      max-width: 460px;
      display: flex;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-image: url("http://snaklvr.com/bg.jpg");
    }
    img {
      float: center;
    }
    .drop_menu li a {
      padding: 12px 5px;
      display: inline-block;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      font: 12px arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    }
    .drop_menu > li {
      border-right: 1px solid #75809a;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .drop_menu > li:last-child {
      border-right: none;
    }
    /* Submenu */
    .drop_menu ul {
      text-align: left;
      position: absolute;
      left: -9999px;
      top: -9999px;
      list-style-type: none;
      display: inline;
    }
    .drop_menu li:hover {
      position: relative;
      background: #75809a;
    }
    .drop_menu li:hover ul {
      left: 0px;
      top: 38px;
      background: #75809a;
      padding: 0px;
    }
    .drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
      padding: 10px;
      display: block;
      width: 168px;
      text-indent: 15px;
      background-color: #75809a;
    }
    .drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover {
      background: #005555;
    }
    
    tbody div {
      overflow: scroll;
      height: 400px;
    }
    
    #InTheCenter {
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    div.topdiv {
      clear: both;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      height: 60%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #bfb9b5;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
      left: 400;
    }
    
    div.bottomdiv {
      clear: both;
      position: fixed;
      top: 60%;
      height: 40%;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #bfb9b5;
      color: #FFFFFF;
      font-size: 16px;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
    var LeftsideMeetingsPopup = document.documentElement.clientWidth / 2 - 550;
    var TopOfMeetingsPopup = document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2 - 300;
    
    var LeftsideEventsPopup = document.documentElement.clientWidth / 2 - 310;
    var TopOfEventsPopup = document.documentElement.clientHeight / 2 - 180;
    
    var MeetingsParams =
      "Width=1100,Height=600,Left=" +
      LeftsideMeetingsPopup +
      ",Top=" +
      TopOfMeetingsPopup +
      ",scrollbars=no";
    var EventsParams =
      "Width=620,Height=360,Left=" +
      LeftsideEventsPopup +
      ",Top=" +
      TopOfEventsPopup +
      ",scrollbars=no";
    
    function Meetings_Popup(mylink, windowname) {
      if (!window.focus) return true;
      var href;
      if (typeof mylink == "string") href = mylink;
      else href = mylink.href;
      window.open(href, windowname, MeetingsParams);
      return false;
    }
    
    function Events_Popup(mylink, windowname) {
      if (!window.focus) return true;
      var href;
      if (typeof mylink == "string") href = mylink;
      else href = mylink.href;
      window.open(href, windowname, EventsParams);
      return false;
    }
  </SCRIPT>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#bfb9b5">
  <div class="topdiv">
    <div class="InTheCenter">
      <br/><img src="http://snaklvr.com/test.jpg" width="940" height="200"><br/>
    </div>
    <div>
      </BR>
      <ul class="drop_menu">
        <li>
          <A href="#" onClick="return Meetings_Popup(this, 'notes')">Meeting List</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <A href="#" onClick="return Events_Popup(this, 'notes')">Events</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <A href='#'>Misc Links</a>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <A target="_blank" href="http://www.amazon.com/">Amazon</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <A target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <A target="_blank" href="https://lowes.com/">Lowes</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```